# Loading STL file with THREE.js in Vue mounted()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, stl

I currently have the problem that I am not able to load a STL file into a three.js scene which is created via vue.js.

The code looks similar to this:

```
<template>
  <div class="GCodeViewer" >

    <div id="canvas"></div>
   
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as THREE from "three";
import { STLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

export default {
  name: "GCodeViewer",
  data: function() {
    return {
      show: this.tabs,
      scene: null,
      renderer: null,
      camera: null,
      controls: null,
      points: [],
      lightHolder: null,
      height: 0,
      object: null,
      nozzle: null,
      raycaster: null,
      mouse: null,
      gcode: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      var self = this;
      var container = document.getElementById("canvas");
      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        clearColor: 0x000000,
        clearAlpha: 1
      });
      var width = (window.innerWidth - 100) / 2;
      var height = window.innerHeight / 2;
      this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
      this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
      container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

      //this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
      //this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

      this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
      this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x50555f);

      var zylinder_mesh = null

      var loader = new STLLoader();
            loader.load( 'stl/example.stl', function ( geometry ) {
                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                      ambient: 0xff5533, 
                      color: 0xff5533, 
                      specular: 0x111111,
                      shininess: 200 }                                         
        );
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        mesh.position.set(0, 100, 0);
        self.scene.add(mesh)
      }, undefined, function ( error ) {console.error( error );} );
      
      console.log(this.scene.children)


      this.points.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, width / height, 1, 10000);
      this.camera.position.y = 250;
      this.camera.position.z = 0;
      this.camera.position.x = -300;
      this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

      var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
      this.scene.add(ambientLight);

      this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
      this.renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.BasicShadowMap;

      this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    },
    animate() {
      this.controls.update();
      requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
  }
  mounted() {
    this.init();
    this.animate();
    //window.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onMouseDown, false);
  }
};
</script>
```

Everything works fine when creating meshes and adding them to the scene within the init() function. However, loading stl files give me the following error (which is an indicator that the file could not be found)

```
GCodeViewer.vue?5fe3:78 RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 6861101076
    at new Float32Array (<anonymous>)
    at parseBinary (STLLoader.js?518e:196)
    at STLLoader.parse (STLLoader.js?518e:393)
    at Object.eval [as onLoad] (STLLoader.js?518e:90)
    at XMLHttpRequest.eval (three.module.js?5a89:36216)
eval @ GCodeViewer.vue?5fe3:78
eval @ STLLoader.js?518e:96
eval @ three.module.js?5a89:36216
load (async)
load @ three.module.js?5a89:36194
load @ STLLoader.js?518e:86
...
```

I some how need to find a way to load the stl file correctly.
Any help would be appreciated!

Best regards
Dominik

Comment: Is the STL displayed when you drag'n'drop it into the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/)?

Comment: Yes, the stl is displayed correctly

Comment: In this case, the problem seems to be on application level. Can you please ensure with the browser's dev tools that your backend actually serves a STL file? Sometimes similar issues occur because web servers do return invalid HTTP responses (like HTML pages).

Comment: I think with the devtools I am not able to find the file (under sources tab). My suggestions is that webpack does not bundle it together with the vue components, even so it is in the same subdirectory as the vue component "GCodeViewer" under ./stl/example.stl.

Comment: I suggest you post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

I moved the .stl file into the public folder. After that I was able to import it with base_url/example.stl

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. yarn add react-scripts
2. rm -rf node_modules/
3. yarn
4. (Optional) if the above does not help, downgrade your Node from version 12 to version 10

Comment: Adding react-scripts and reinstalling all node modules did not solve the problem.
I did not try out 4. yet.